# How to differentiate between NT Windows and User Windows? I got all mixed up

Tags: windows, ms-dos, windows-nt-4

I got a confusion in Older Version of Windows for example how to differentiate between NT Windows 3.1 & User Windows 1.01 to 3.11, Windows 95, 98 etc.

I simple words I am mixing User and NT Windows.

Can someone clarify how to differentiate between them? Actually my course requires it to study them

Comment: Why would you want to recognize something that's been obsolete for decades?  Windows versions before 3.1 simply were not commonly used (like in almost no one actually used them).  `winver` probably existed back in NT but I can't be sure it did before that though.

Comment: [Since Win2000 its all NT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT#Releases). "DOS based" line ended at ME. Before that NT versions simply had NT in name ;)

Comment: @Julie Pelletier That's a good question but actually, my course requires it to study and  my teacher doesn't teach well

Comment: I too busy for nice answer right now, but I believe [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions) should be all you need. "Release Version" will tell you which is NT.

Comment: @PTwr should make that an answer, if this answers your question. Then you can approve it and vote it up.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Some of us are old enough to have used Windows 2.11 as well as early versions of MS/DOS IBM/DOS...

Comment: If your course requires you to study them, I suppose they must give you a way to install them too, which could be done on old scrap or in VMs.  That way you'd be able to experience them first hand.

Comment: @DavidPostill:  That wasn't my point.  Windows 2.11 probably didn't have more than a few K users worldwide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt anyone uses the old dos based versions of windows older than 3.11, but using the precise versions is a good idea, since they were familes all on their own.

95/98/ME were a second family of OSes, seperate kernel and APIs for most part. Most folks call it windows 9x.

In theory windows NT's its own family, though I'd suggest differentiating NT,3.51 and 4.0 from 2K and later - since there was no workstation version before 2k, and XP.

In theory, vista onwards were pretty major rewrites, but will run most things XP did.